# How does qBittorent Web UI work?

Tags: remote-access, qbittorrent, html-files

How does qBittorent Web UI work?

I mean, how does a web page access to a software installed in the computer like qBittorent?

Can an HTML file which run on localhost access to an installed software like that?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What research have you done regarding this? An application can have any of several different UIs, or no UI at all. Web UIs have some limitations, but if they are being run on localhost they generally have more abilities than the permissions a public or external website would have on your computer. The main point is that the software is running a web server and is able to send and receive info from the site it is presenting, and use that to control the software underlying it.

Answer (score 1):

> Can an HTML file which run on localhost access to an installed software like that?

Yeah – by talking *to localhost.* The built-in web server inside qBittorrent doesn't just serve the static HTML; it also serves an API that can be used e.g. from JavaScript through AJAX/XHR/Fetch (or from oldschool HTML POST forms, or possibly from a different client, or from an Android app, etc). And because the server is running *inside* qBittorrent, it can control the rest of the program.

Functionally it is very much the same as any other webapp that uses JavaScript and XHR/AJAX (or forms) to access some server-side logic.